# How to draw polygon with radius around polyline in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, polygon, google-polyline

I have problem with drawing polygon around polyline(( I have all coordinates polyline and i want to buffer the coordinates to get coordinates of polygon around this polyline.

I have something like ***this***: [image].

But I want to make something like ***this***:

[image]

please help...

Comment: Could you not just draw the poly line again with a different colour and bigger line width?

Answer (score 2):

You can just draw 2 polylines with same path.

Let's say you've created a variable `thePath` with buffered coordinates.
You've already created a polyline with this path.

```
let redPolyline = GMSPolyline()
redPolyline.path = thePath
redPolyline.map = mapview
```

Create another one.

```
let redPolyline = GMSPolyline()
redPolyline.path = thePath
redPolyline.strokeWidth = 6.0 // Change it accordingly 
redPolyline.strokeWidth = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5) // Change it accordingly

redPolyline.map = mapview
```

Remember to that redPolyline's `zIndex` should be higher than the bluePolyline because as i can see in the image you've provided, redPolyline is on top of the other one.

Comment: Yes but it is not quite correct decision. I need to set the distance to draw this polygon, because I need to add further points (Google Places), which is in thiw area (eg 20 km)

This decisions when to approach polilayn area is also reduced ((

For Java and Java script has the solution https://github.com/dr-jts/jts/tree/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/operation/buffer

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to draw polygone on Google map with array coordinates use this function:

func addPloygone(){
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        path.removeAllCoordinates()
        for i in places{
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:i.lon!, longitude:i.lat!))
            let polyline = GMSPolygon(path: path)
            polyline.geodesic = true
            polyline.map = map
            polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.black
            polyline.fillColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed:176/255, green: 143/255, blue:52/255, alpha: 0.6)
        }
    }
```